# Select random row from table making sure that row has not been rated

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm selecting a random row from a table with sequential records:

```
  $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table");
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($total);
  $stmt->fetch();
  $stmt->close();

  $rand = mt_rand(1,$total);

  $try = 0;

  do {

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id,link,(select count(*) from $table2 where img_id=? AND ip=?) FROM $table WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("isi",$rand,$ip,$rand);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id,$link,$count);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();

    $try++;

  } while ($try < 10 && $count > 0);
```

I'm checking if a user has rated a particular thing before based on their IP.

I get a random number between the first record and the last one with `mt_rand(1,$total)`, then I select that row.

However, the user may have already rated that particular item before, then I need to 're-select' or try for another random row, and here I try 10 times before giving up in the program.

Any way in SQL to do this better or make sure I select one they have never rated before without the whole inefficient try do while thingy? I can't use `ORDER BY RAND()` because it's too slow.

Comment: How are you keeping track of what the user has already rated?

Comment: why not execute your SQL, excluding IP, and populate an array.  Then choose a random array element.

Comment: @Nicarus `$table2` with the fields `img_id` and `ip`. check the second prepare. I should note that it's guest rating too, you don't need an account